# Why am I getting two dialog box confirmations (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click the link to delete a comment I receive two dialog box confirmations. When I remove the confirmation I don't get any.

view/comments/_comment:

```
<span class="comment_info">
  <aside class="span2">
    <%= link_to gravatar_for((comment.user), size: 35), comment.user %>
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user, id: "feedusername" %>
  </aside>
<span id="comment_contentz"> <%= comment.content %>
<span id="timestamp_and_delete">
  Said <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
  <% if current_user?(comment.user) || current_user.id == (comment.micropost.user_id) %>
    <%= link_to "erase", comment, method: :delete, id:"",
            data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
            title: comment.content %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I have the same problem with my posts

Microposts/_micropost:

```
  <span class="timestamp">Posted  
    <%=time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.</span>
    <%= render 'shared/delete_micropost', object: micropost %> </span>
    <br/>
    <%= micropost.content %>
  </span>
<%= render micropost.comments %>
```

shared/delete_micropost:

```
<% if current_user?(object.user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", object, method: :delete,        id:"micropost_delete",
            data: { confirm: "Remove Post?" },
            title: object.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tested to take away `dependent: :destroy` just to see what happens?

Comment: yea same problem. It must have to do with something I added recently because I Don't remember getting this problem before, but the issue is i dont know when it started exactly

Comment: Is there a way to test what calls the second confirmation?

Comment: If it was me I would try only `confirm: "Remove Post?"` (not the whole `data: ...`, I'm using old Rails so perhaps it's correct as you use it). I also would have looked at the generated HTML code. I'm using Firebug in Firefox, very useful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when a click handler is bound twice to the same element. Check that your javascript files aren't included twice.

If you're on Rails 3.2.8, look for multiple includes of `application.js` or `jquery_ujs`. Alternatively you can try setting a breakpoint using the Javascript console on the click handler that is called when you click on the delete button. You'll have to dig for that method somewhere in the aforementioned files.

If that breakpoint gets hit twice, then you probably have included that file twice. If it gets hit only once, then some other code is setting a click handler on the same element.

Caveat: like 244an said in his comment on your post, you don't have to put the `confirm: "You sure?` inside of a data hash. You can just do this: `<%= link_to 'erase', delete_path, confirm: 'You sure?' %>`. See [UrlHelper#link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Doesn't seem to hurt anything, though, to do it the way you did.

Comment: My javascript is definitely firing twice through out the app but i dont know where the problem is. In my server when i click something I see: Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML Processing by MicropostsController#create as JS

Comment: Do you see that in the logs after you hit 'yes' on both dialog boxes, or does that appear in the logs when you load the page with the offending link?

BTW you can use something like [git bisect](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) to help you find the offending commit. Then it might be as easy as viewing the diff to see where code is getting included twice or a click handler assigned twice.

Comment: i just figured it out. I had to delete the public/assets folder, restart the server and clear the browser cache. there were repeats of application.js in the pub/asset folder.